# Disabling Viewstate for page with only Formview

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

1. I have a page with Formview that shows a row of a table in database.

I've no other operations to be performed other than navigating to other pages.

Can I disable View state for page like this?
For this scenario, I've all the functionality inside of

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
//all the functionality
    }
```

1. I've another page with 4 repeaters that just shows the 10 latest Titles of  4 different categories.
   There are no other databound controls in this page. Only I can navigate to other pages via links. 
   Can I disable the view state for page like this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you don't intend to retrieve the data you've bound into those controls, if you don't need to access anything about them on postback, you can disable viewstate without difficulty on those pages.